# Change resource group in Azure Solution

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-resource-group, azure-vm

In our Azure i've chreated start/stop VM solution. This solution was targeted to our default resource group. And now I want to target this solution to another resource group, because whis solution mast be applied not to all VMs.  How can I change resourse group in solution? Or it is impossible and I should to recreate solution?
any help will be appreciated, PS scripts especcialy (try to deep dive in Azure PS Scriptin)

Comment: How are you reading the resource group in you function?

Comment: a have no function yet. Just now i have a task - configure start-stop solution to work with certain resource group

Answer (score 0):

You can using the portal, Azure CLI or powershell. As it is a VM you'll have to move its supporting resources. Fortunatelly, microsoft has a git repo of example scripts that you can follow and study.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines/linux/move-vm.md

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines/windows/move-vm.md